# Pandas Multiply Specific Columns by Value In Row

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I am attempting to multiple specific columns a value in their respective row.

For example:

```
          X         Y         Z
A 10      1         0         1        
B 50      0         0         0      
C 80      1         1         1
```

Would become:

```
              X         Y         Z
A 10        10         0         10        
B 50        0          0         0      
C 80        80         80        80
```

The problem I am having is that it is timing out when I use mul(). My real dataset is very large. I tried to iterate it with loop in my real code as follows:

```
for i in range(1,df_final_small.shape[0]): 
    df_final_small.iloc[i].values[3:248] = df_final_small.iloc[i].values[3:248] * df_final_small.iloc[i].values[2]
```

Which when applied to the example dataframe would look like this:

```
for i in range(1,df_final_small.shape[0]): 
    df_final_small.iloc[i].values[1:4] = df_final_small.iloc[i].values[1:4] * df_final_small.iloc[i].values[0]
```

There must be a better way to do this, I am having problems figuring out how to only cast the multiplication to certain columns in the row rather than the entire row.

EDIT:
To detail further here is my df.head(5).

```
id  gross   150413 Welcome Email    150413 Welcome Email Repeat Cust    151001 Welcome Email    151001 Welcome Email Repeat Cust    161116 eKomi    1702 Hot Leads Email    1702 Welcome Email - All Purchases  1804 Hot Leads  ... SILVER  GOLD    PLATINUM    Acquisition Direct Mail Conversion Direct Mail  Retention Direct Mail   Retention eMail cluster x   y
0   0033333 46.2    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 10  -0.230876   0.461990
1   0033331 2359.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 9   0.231935    -0.648713
2   0033332 117.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 5   -0.812921   -0.139403
3   0033334 89.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 5   -0.812921   -0.139403
4   0033335 1908.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 7   -0.974142   0.145032
```

Comment: Is the index `A 50`, and you need to extract the number from that?

Comment: can you print `df.head(5)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want to multiply. Example

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':10,'X':1,'Y':1,'Z':1},index=[1])
df.loc[:,['X', 'Y', 'Z']]=df.loc[:,['X', 'Y', 'Z']].values*df.iloc[:,0:1].values
```

If want to provide an arbitrary range of columns use iloc

```
range_of_columns= range(10,5001)+range(5030,10001)
df.iloc[:,range_of_columns].values*df.iloc[:,0:1].values #multiplying the range of columns with the first column
```

Comment: This is what I had done previously, but I do not want to definite over 10,000 columns in the future when sections for instance 10-5000 and 5030-10000 need to be normalized by multiplication.

Comment: Using your solution: df=pd.DataFrame({'A':10,'X':1,'Y':1,'Z':1},index=[1])
df.loc[:,['X', 'Y', 'Z']].values*df.iloc[:,0:1].values
df = df.loc[:,['X', 'Y', 'Z']].values*df.iloc[:,0:1].values
print df Results in an numpy array, I want to edit the entire dataframe.

Comment: mad_ the the update is closer but is not running for my dataset, the gross column (column 2) has been added to your second solution as well as the range of columns I wanted to multiply by as detailed in my questions attempt here is the code I used based on your second solution: range_of_columns= range(3,248)
df_final_small.iloc[:,range_of_columns].values*df_final_small.iloc[:,0:2].values      The output is as follows: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,245) (5,2)

Comment: To clarify, I want to multiple the column 'gross' column 2 by columns 3 to 248.

Comment: mad_ I am not sure what you are saying, could you clarify what edits you would like me to make? The index column posted in my df.head(5) is not one of the columns. Column 0 is id and column 1 is gross. My question still stands, the previous commend was a typo, my apologies it should have read: To clarify, I want to multiple the column 'gross' column 1 by columns 3 to 248.

Comment: My apologies mad_ did not mean to confuse you. I made the correction as you said but there is still a problem, the resulting dataframe has dropped the id values as well as all the other columns that will be needed. I can probably figure out how to stitch them back together, but that isn't optimal.

Comment: Accepted answer as it was closest to what was needed.

Answer (score 3):

Using `mul` with `axis = 0` also get the `index` value by `get_level_values`

```
df.mul(df.index.get_level_values(1),axis=0)
Out[167]: 
       X   Y   Z
A 10  10   0  10
B 50   0   0   0
C 80  80  80  80
```

Also when the dataframe is way to big , you can split it and do it by chunk .

```
dfs = np.split(df, [2], axis=0)
pd.concat([x.mul(x.index.get_level_values(1), axis=0) for x in dfs])
Out[174]: 
       X   Y   Z
A 10  10   0  10
B 50   0   0   0
C 80  80  80  80
```

Also I will recommend `numpy` broadcast

```
df.values*df.index.get_level_values(1)[:,None]
Out[177]: Int64Index([[10, 0, 10], [0, 0, 0], [80, 80, 80]], dtype='int64')
pd.DataFrame(df.values*df.index.get_level_values(1)[:,None],index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
Out[181]: 
       X   Y   Z
A 10  10   0  10
B 50   0   0   0
C 80  80  80  80
```

Comment: I am getting an index error for both my full dataset and the test case: IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 3

Comment: I think that is another column. Just looking at OP's solution

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=17692, step=1)

Comment: To clarify, please see my original dataset, I only want to multiply gross by the fields that either contain 0 or 1, there are other columns that I do not want to multiply by. Attempting your third solution now.

Comment: @JosephPNardone it is kind of unclear , maybe consider fix your sample dataframe

Comment: @Wen I have added a sample dataframe of my actual data, I figured my example would have made it easier to understand, I apologize. Please see my df.head(5) to see why this solution does not work.